# How do I update my training data by loading a new chunk from a file with theano?

Tags: python, loading, theano

I am loading image files for a neural network, and their size becomes nontrivial when they are read into numpy. Currently I have all the files as .png files on my hard drive.  I can safely load the file names and the response variable, since they are several orders of magnitude less than the images themselves.

I would like to read them like this:

```
def open_files(files_list,indexes):
    file_subset = files_list[indexes[0]:indexes[1]]
    input_arrays = []
    for file in file_subset:
        img = Image.open(file)
        img.load()
        data = np.asarray(img,dtype="int32")
        input_arrays.append(data)
    return np.asarray(input_arrays)
```

I have my givens defined as follows

```
train_model = theano.function(
    [index],
    cost,
    updates=updates,
    givens={
        x:open_files(training_files,(index*batch_size,(index + 1)*batch_size)),
        y:training_y[index*batch-size:(index + 1)*batch_size]
    }
)
```

Obviously, this doesn't work as I get an IndexError from an invalid slice, but I am not sure how to get theano to update something that isn't already in memory.  It should be possible, as part of [the tutorial I am reading](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/gettingstarted.html) is as follows:

> If you are running your code on the GPU and the dataset you are using is too large to fit in memory the code will crash. In such a case you should store the data in a shared variable. You can however store a sufficiently small chunk of your data (several minibatches) in a shared variable and use that during training. Once you got through the chunk, update the values it stores. This way you minimize the number of data transfers between CPU memory and GPU memory.

How do I do this?